# The hiring problem extension

Tags: probability

Some Background:

**Some instance of the Hiring problem is as following:**

let $a_1$,...,$a_n$ be candidates for a job in some company, assume the company interviews one of them at a time, and their arrival for the interview is totally random, also assume $a_1$ is the worst candidate and  $a_n$ is the best.

the company hires a candidate only if they havent already hired a better candidate, whats the probability that  $a_i$ (for some i) is hired?

answer : $1/(n-i+1)$ because candidate $a_i$  must interview first out of {$a_i$,...,$a_n$}.

now that you have the background...

**my question is even worse instance of the hiring problem:**

let $a_1$,...,$a_n$ be candidates for a job in some company, assume the company interviews one of them at a time, and their arrival for the interview is totally random, also assume $a_1$ is the worst candidate and  $a_n$ is the best.

the company starts by employing the first 2 candidates, and ever since the company deploys the better candidate as manager and the worst as a simple worker. the company hires a candidate only if he is better then any one of their current employees.

1. whats the probability that  $a_i$ is hired as a manager?
2. whats the probability that $a_i$ is hired as a simple worker?

I am having troubles dealing with this, i could use some help...

**So far my directions are :**

1. $0$ if $i=1$, and $1/(n-i+1)$ else because $a_i$ must come first out of {$a_i$,...,$a_n$}.
2. $0$ if $i=n$, else $1/(n-i+1)$ because for any other i a manager will eventually be a simple worker. and i'm missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

if i=1 then there are n better than him
so its 1/n
which means its still 1/(n-i+1)

what is the probability of Ai becoming a simple worker..
he needs to be chosen second between all those who are better than him...

so my guess is someone must be choosen better than him which is 1/(n-i-1)
but then then u will have to choose Ai himself between all what's left so the probability of that is 
1/(n-1)
so 
1/(n-i+1)*1/(n-1)... 
thats just a wild guess so dont really rely on me

my smart friend says 1/(n-i)